# opening an agent via SSJS in XPages including parameters

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotusscript, xpages-ssjs

I want to open an agent via an URL and provide some additional parameters (re-writing an old Domino app, I want to maintain some document handling that resides now in web enabled agents)

I am trying:

```
...
var unid:String=mybean.myObject().getUnid();
importPackage(java.net);
importPackage(java.io);
var agent:URL = new URL("myagent?OpenAgent&unid=" + unid);
var agentConnection:URLConnection = agent.openConnection();
...
```

this causes an error. if I look in the log the address I am directing to has become: "dir/db.nsf/myagent?OpenAgent&unid=7FC612D6736836ECC125822800622FF1"

any easy way to get this old agent running?

Comment: You probably need a complete URL with protocol and host name as input for the URL object.

Comment: naaa I skipped that in the example code above. does not work with full URL.

Comment: What is the exact error? Also, please don't "skip things" in example code. If you're going to mention what the URL has become, then you obviously think it's significant and you make us think that, too. By leaving part of it out, you end up wasting people's time.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to revisit your approach. Instead of using http(s) to access your agent, you could call it directly with agent.run. It would require some adjustment on the agent side (still can be used dual use) and saves you the TLS headache. Follow this blog entry for inspiration: https://wissel.net/blog/2012/04/reuse-web-agents-that-use-print-bean-edition.html

Answer (score 0):

Does your server or database use only https? I think that requires different code and there are issues with Java 1.6 and TLS versions.